# ggplot2: Save directly to harddrive

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that the combination of `ggplot()` and then `ggsave()` will create and save the plots to the hard drive.

Is there any chance of directly saving the graph to the hard drive without showing/displaying it first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to save the ggplot into a variable, then define plot in ggsave, like so:

```
testplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, qsec)) + geom_point()
ggsave('test.png', plot = testplot)
```